# How to adjust Jenkins weather report for clover coverage on PHP projects

Tags: continuous-integration, phpunit, jenkins, code-coverage

I have a few PHP projects installed for a new team in Jenkins, and I'm trying to lower the expectations initially to help ramp them up on testing and everything.  Initially we're shooting for 20% code coverage. I've adjusted the bounds in my PHPUnit config file to go green on code coverage when they hit 20% - so they can see they're heading in the right direction.  but what I'm trying to do is update the weather report in my jenkins views to reflect the clover coverage as well, and I can't seem to do that!

[image: Jenkins Weather Report Clover Coverage]

I have the *Publish Clover PHP Coverage Report* checked in my jenkins project configuration, and my clover.xml is being generated from PHPUnit, but I'm not sure how to adjust the bounds for this.

**logging from phpunit.xml.dist:**

```
<logging>
  <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="ERC"
     charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
     lowUpperBound="10" highLowerBound="20"/>
  <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
  <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
```

**Project settings coverage metrics**

I initially didn't have the *Publish Html Report* enabled, but I've found that enabling it and modifying the percentages never had any affect after I saved and re-ran the build.
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It appears to be a bug. I hope you don't mind, but I used your images to open a new issue in their bug tracker: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20233 This plugin doesn't have that many open issues so hopefully they'll notice and fix it.

Comment: Ya, no problem, hopefully it gets fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

The bounds for the Jenkins weather report are defined in Jenkins and not in phpunit

[image]

It might look a little different for you depending on whether you use the Clover or the CloverPHP plugin but it's in the Jenkins settings page ether way :)

Comment: thanks for the input - I tried playing with the coverage metrics a couple different ways, but I could never get the cloud/sun to change besides changing the actual code coverage (assume its still reading in default values). We're using the **Jenkins Clover PHP Plugin**. I'll update my original post to include a snapshot of what I put settings at, but nothing I seem to change has any affect.

Comment: Point taken, there actually seems to be a problem with that and the clover php plugin. What works it using the CloverPlugin and putting a -1 in the third col that phpunit doesn't provide but thats not really pretty. I'll need to investigate

Comment: @edorian did you ever find the cause/solution to this problem? Is there somewhere "proper" I can follow this up, like an issue tracker for the PHP Clover Plugin?

Comment: @NilsLuxton Nope. I didn't find a solution and the plugin hasn't received any updates since then ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clover+PHP+Plugin ) Opening a bug report at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa might help.